# How do I parse command arguments in quotes, in discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

The title explains most of it.
I want to make a poll command:

```
  const args = message.content.slice(1).trim().split(/ +/g); // trims the args
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase(); // finds the actual command
    const guild = message.guild;
client.on("message", async message => {

   if (command === "poll") {
        const poll = new Discord.RichEmbed().setColor('#' + (0x1000000 + (Math.random()) * 0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1, 6));
        if (args) {
            if (message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "poller")) {
                var upvote = message.guild.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name == 'Upvote');
                var downvote = message.guild.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name == 'Downvote');
                let sendTo = "";
                sendTo+=(args[0]);
                sendTo += (upvote + args[1]);
                sendTo += ("\n\n" + downvote + args[2]);
                message.channel.send(sendTo)
                    .then(function(message) {
                        message.react(guild.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name === "Upvote"));
                        message.react(guild.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name === "Downvote"));
                    }).catch(function() {
                        poll.setDescription("Error has occured. Stopping process.");
                        poll.setFooter('Unknown error has occured. Terminating action 000921.');
                        message.channel.send(poll);
                    });
                message.delete().catch(O_o => {});
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Failed");
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem here is that I need multiple words for the polls, but even with quotes, it still will just return it as if it's normal.
e.g ;poll "test 1" "test 2" "test 3" returns "test :upvote:1" :downvote:"test.
What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```js
const pollOptions = message.content.match(/".+?"/g).map(str => str.replace(/"/g, ''))

// ;poll "Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3"
// pollOptions would equal ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3']
```

---

Code snippet example:

```js
const input = '"Option 1" and also "Option 2", and maybe "Option 3" as well'
const updated = input.match(/".+?"/g).map(str => str.replace(/"/g, ''))

console.log(updated) // isolating whatever's within the quotes
```